Section bibliography with multiple languages using biblatex with biber backend
Putting together my dissertation thesis with several published works, I would like to provide section-wise bibliographies and a collected bibliography at the end.
Since I am using APA as my citation format, for in-text references with two authors, both authors must be written out and connected by the word "and". Now, one article is written in German, and the "and" is supposed to be translated, however only in this one article.
Additionally, of course, there may be special words in the bibliography that would need to be translated as well (e.g., "edition").
Additional info: Several articles share some references, and I wouldn't want to have to manage multiple language versions of these articles.
See this MWE:
\documentclass[12pt,twoside=on,appendixprefix,paper=a4,headings=small]{scrbook}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=apa,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{myliterature.bib}
    @Article{bishara2017confidence,
        author    = {Bishara, Anthony J and Hittner, James B},
        title     = {Confidence intervals for correlations when data are not normal},
        journal   = {Behavior research methods},
        year      = {2017},
        volume    = {49},
        number    = {1},
        pages     = {294--309},
        publisher = {Springer},
    }
    @Article{bueker2012stochastic,
        author    = {Büker, Thorsten and Seybold, Bernhard},
        title     = {Stochastic modelling of delay propagation in large networks},
        journal   = {Journal of Rail Transport Planning \& Management},
        year      = {2012},
        volume    = {2},
        number    = {1-2},
        pages     = {34--50},
        publisher = {Elsevier},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{myliterature.bib}


\begin{document}
    \chapter{These works belong together}
    \begin{refsection}
        \section[English Article]{English Article - full title (en-US)}
        \textcite{bishara2017confidence}
        \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    \end{refsection}

    \begin{refsection}
        \section[German Article]{German Article - full title (de-DE)}
        \textcite{bueker2012stochastic}
        \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]     
    \end{refsection}

\end{document}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Edit: I've edited the question by providing an MWE. I would be interested in a generalizable solution.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for the comment. You are absolutely correct. Initially, I felt that in this case it wasn't necessary. Now, I've edited the question accordingly.

If you use e.g. babel to switch languages, biblatex will automatically translate strings like and etc.:
\documentclass[12pt,twoside=on,appendixprefix,paper=a4,headings=small]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=apa,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{myliterature.bib}
    @Article{bishara2017confidence,
        author    = {Bishara, Anthony J and Hittner, James B},
        title     = {Confidence intervals for correlations when data are not normal},
        journal   = {Behavior research methods},
        year      = {2017},
        volume    = {49},
        number    = {1},
        pages     = {294--309},
        publisher = {Springer},
    }
    @Article{bueker2012stochastic,
        author    = {Büker, Thorsten and Seybold, Bernhard},
        title     = {Stochastic modelling of delay propagation in large networks},
        journal   = {Journal of Rail Transport Planning \& Management},
        year      = {2012},
        volume    = {2},
        number    = {1-2},
        pages     = {34--50},
        publisher = {Elsevier},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{myliterature.bib}


\begin{document}
    \chapter{These works belong together}
    \begin{refsection}
        \section[English Article]{English Article - full title (en-US)}
        \textcite{bishara2017confidence}
        \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    \end{refsection}

    \begin{refsection}
        \selectlanguage{ngerman}
        \section[German Article]{German Article - full title (de-DE)}
        \textcite{bueker2012stochastic}
        \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]     
    \end{refsection}
    
\textcite{bueker2012stochastic}    
\nocite{*}    
\printbibliography

\end{document}


